# Normal for app.xctest to be red under products folder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I just renamed my Xcode project and was wondering if its normal for the `app.xctest` to be in red.

The `.app` isn't red, its normal.

I looked at other projects i have and they sometimes are red sometimes aren't so i just want to make sure.

I tried doing a clean build but its still red.

but my iOS app runs fine on my iPhone.

Seems like everything is working fine but the red is bugging me and just need to know if i need to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal. XCode just says that it's no such file created. This file is intended for testing your app and in this case red != an exception.